# Nonvanishing vector fields on $\mathbf{S}^2$ and bases for $T_p\mathbf{S}^2$.

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, vector-analysis, smooth-manifolds

A vector field on a manifold is a (continuous, differentiable) map $X: M \to TM$ such that $X(p) \in T_pM$ for each $p \in M$. The tangent space $T_pM$ has a basis.

Take $M = \mathbf{S}^2$. For each $p \in \mathbf{S}^2$ there is a basis for $T_p\mathbf{S}^2$ consisting of two vectors $v_p$ and $w_p$. Hence (I think) vector fields on $\mathbf{S}^2$ are exactly the maps of the form $p \mapsto f(p)v_p + g(p)w_p$ for some (continuous, differentiable) maps $f, g: \mathbf{S}^2 \to \mathbf{R}$.

So, considering this, why doesn't, say, the vector field $p \mapsto v_p$ give a counterexample to the [Hairy Ball theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hairy_ball_theorem), i.e. a nonvanishing vector field? Since $v_p$ and $w_p$ form a basis for $T_p\mathbf{S}^2$, $v_p$ is never zero, right?

As you can see, I am confused. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Sure, at a given point $p$, you can pick $v_p$ and $w_p$ as you say. But now try to do it in a consistent way at all points of $S^2$...

Comment: I had in mind the the vectors $\mathbf{\hat{\theta}}$ and $\mathbf{\hat{\phi}}$ on [this page](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SphericalCoordinates.html). What do you mean by consistent?

Comment: Which direction does $\hat \phi$ point at the top of the sphere? Or the bottom? Same question for $\hat \theta$.

Comment: By consistent I just meant giving a well-defined map defined at all points of $M$, rather than fixing a point and arbitrarily choosing a basis at that point. As for your other question, what @SamDeHority said.

Comment: Let me be a little bit more precise. The vector field $\hat{\theta}$ is perfectly well-defined on the sphere, but it vanishes at the poles. On the other hand, $\hat{\phi}$ is not well-defined at the poles: it wants to point in all directions at once.